# Convert Bits to Int8 Haskell

Tags: haskell, byte, bit, bit-shift, ghci

Trying to convert a list of Bits (0,1) into an Int8 or something similar so that I am not wasting a byte from ByteString on only 1 bit

For example, I may have a list like [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0], which as a ByteString represents each of those as a Byte instead of a Bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to just fold over the list:

```
import Data.Bits (Bits, shiftL, (.|.))

pack :: (Num b, Foldable t, Bits b) => t b -> b
pack a = foldl go 0 a
    where go acc i = (acc `shiftL` 1) .|. i
```

and you get:

```
\> pack [0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0]
286
```

Comment: @astiefel you can convert across numeric types; see https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers

Comment: is there a way to reverse it? Because I have the following unpack method: `unpack :: Word8 -> [Word8]
unpack 0 = [0]
unpack x = reverse (go x) where
  go 0 = []
  go n | n `mod` 2 == 1 = 1 : go (n `div` 2)
       | n `mod` 2 == 0 = 0 : go (n `div` 2)
       | otherwise      = []` but I cannot pack and then unpack